# Looping through a set of <p>'s one at a time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of p's so every time the button is pressed, it outputs to 0 to 1 until the maximum number of p's is counted.

```
var big_number = 999999;
var i;
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
function function0() {
for (i=0; i < big_number; i++) { 
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].innerHTML="text";
  }
}
```

I want it to write to another p every time the button is pressed.

Comment: an array of nodes has a length property that stores the number of elements.

Comment: $('p').length would be better

Comment: @nurdyguy: You're assuming the OP is using jQuery. I see no sign of that in the question, but he could just as easily use `a.length` in his code above.

Comment: When you say you want it to output 0 to 1 until the max number of p's, do you want those paragraph tags to hold these numbers? Or just write 0 to #p's in the console?

Comment: I really don't understand what you need, the title of your post says something, its body says another thing and your code says something far different.

Comment: @Travesty3  Yes, it is a pretty big assumption on my part.  I should have said something in it like "Using jQuery, try this...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a generic tag adder function then call it:

```
function addTags(tagName,start, max, container) {
  var i = start;
  for (i; i < max; i++) {
    var newp = document.createElement(tagName);
    newp.innerHTML = "paragraph" + i;
    container.appendChild(newp);
  }
}
var tag = 'p';
var big_number = 30;
var i;
var a = document.getElementsByTagName(tag );
// **THIS is your specific question answer**:
var pCount = a.length;
var parent = document.getElementById('mydiv');
addTags(tag,pCount , big_number, parent);
// add 10 more
a = document.getElementsByTagName(tag );
pCount = a.length;
big_number = big_number+10;
addTags(tag,pCount , big_number, parent);
```

---

**EDIT:**
NOTE: THIS might be better, only hitting the DOM once, up to you to determine need:

```
function addTagGroup(tagName, start, max, container) {
  var tempContainer = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var i = start;
  for (i; i < max; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement(tagName);
    el.textContent = "Paragraph" + i;
    tempContainer.appendChild(el);
  }
  container.appendChild(tempContainer);
}
```

Comment: In my limited testing the second was faster by a 21 to 34 ratio or approx 30 percent faster

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p").length // number of p elements on the page
```

Is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 0):

To find out how many `<p>` elements there are in the document you should use DOM's length property as below :-

```
var numP = document.getElementsByTagName("P").length;
```

or

```
var div = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var numP = div.getElementsByTagName("P").length;
```

To get number of element inside a tag.

Comment: No need to write program for everything just make yourself familiar with DOM properties. with DOM everything will be so easy.....